# Compiler Error C2664 - after changing from Debug to Release rebuild

Tags: windows, visual-studio, release

Disclaimer : Started this a few months back and now revisiting. Still not working much with Visual Studio and Windows API.

The code works when built as Debug X86.

The issue is when I switch from Debug to Release and rebuild the following errors appear.

[image]

The lines of code causing the issue are :

```
 _tprintf("Invalid Handle  %s   <DIR>\n", szDir);
```

and

```
    _tprintf("Error\n");
```

I tried changing the project from characterset to None, Unicode, MultiByte characters but they all generated the same errors.

Any idea why simply changing from Debug to Release causes this issue and how to resolve?
This is something I would have expected when changing from X86 to X64.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    LARGE_INTEGER filesize;
    TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
    size_t length_of_arg;
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    DWORD dwError = 0;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("\nUsage: %s <directory name>\n"), argv[0]);
        return (-1);
    }

    StringCchLength(argv[1], MAX_PATH, &length_of_arg);

    if (length_of_arg > (MAX_PATH - 3))
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("\nDirectory path is too long.\n"));
        return (-1);
    }

    _tprintf(TEXT("\nTarget directory is %s\n\n"), argv[1]);

    StringCchCopy(szDir, MAX_PATH, argv[1]);
    StringCchCat(szDir, MAX_PATH, TEXT("\\*"));

    hFind = FindFirstFile(szDir, &ffd);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind)
    {
        _tprintf("Invalid Handle  %s   <DIR>\n", szDir);
        return dwError;
    }
    :
    ///Doing other stuff here....
    :    
    dwError = GetLastError();
    if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
    {
        //DisplayErrorBox(TEXT("FindFirstFile"));
        _tprintf("Error\n");
    }
    FindClose(hFind);
    return dwError;
}
```

Comment: Using tchar.h is a mistake these days.  But as long as you do, you do have to use the TEXT() macro consistently to avoid this error.

Comment: Thanks. Using TEXT(...) worked.   Any idea why simply changed from DEBUG to RELEASE caused this to happen?????   Instead of tchar.h, what is the recommended header file to user?

Comment: You probably have some other setting different between Debug and Release, such as the character set (on the extended page of the project properties)

Comment: Ok, you are correct. I thought that setting was at the Project level. Just checked and it does change between Debug and Release. Thanks.